# How to prevent VLC from setting as default player?

Tags: macos, catalina, vlc, mediaplayer

I have VLC & Elmedia players. I want to use Elmedia as a default player, but VLC is set as default for all extensions, and I can't change it.

If I choose "Always open with" for some media file, VLC still stays default for this extension.

How to fix it? macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click (Control click) on the type of file you want to always open with Elmedia. Click '**Get Info**'.

In the '**Open With**' section, select Elmedia from the drop-down menu. To apply this change to all files of this type, click the '**Change All**' button. Repeat with any other file types as desired/when they come up

[image]